# Npm refusing to install on Linux Ubuntu displaying “you have held broken packages”

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have nodejs installed but every time I run sudo apt install npm it displays “you have held broken packages.”

I’m not sure why it’s refusing to install but I have tried every possible solution.

Comment: You should not need to install npm separately. It should be available after installing Node.js. How did you install Node.js and did you try `npm -v` after installing it?

Comment: Yea and it’s still not working, I have no idea why.